# iphone <-> real world connection

Tags: iphone, serial-communication

Any pointers on how to initiate serial communication with the iphone?  Or any other idea to interact with external hardware?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only supported way to connect external hardware to the iPhone is through the iPod accessory protocol, through the 30-pin connector.  Details on that program are at http://developer.apple.com/ipod/accessories.html.  It isn't a free program and the 30-pin connector only supports certain features, but it's the only option available today.

Answer (score 2):

Apps compiled with the unofficial toolkit (and running on jailbroken iPhones) can supposedly access the serial port present in the dock connector.

See:
http://devdot.wikispaces.com/Iphone+Serial+Port+Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do. For an SSH terminal connection I reccomend TouchTerm (search the appstore).

I have no experience with electrical connections, but you can find the pinout of the iPod/iPhone connector here:
http://pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/ipod_pinout.shtml

You can then download the iPhone developer kit here:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/