# Mobile supporting AT+CNMI For kannel

Tags: mobile, at-command, kannel, mo, mt

I am looking for mobiles that support AT+CMNI commands to use them as a gsm modem for kannel , because AT+CMNI commands supported mobiles will allow the both MO and MT SMS.

Any suggesting will be welcome , and if there are a way to test if a mobile support AT+CMNI without buying it that will be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AT+CMNI` command is standardized in [27.005](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm) and it says

> **Implementation**
>
> Mandatory when any of the new message indications implemented.

so I think you will have a hard time finding a mobile phone that does not support the `AT+CMNI` command.

Comment: Does that mean that all new smartphones will support this stuff?

Comment: @larnouch Yes, but stay away from Apple's phones since in best case they are [difficult to communicate with](http://stackoverflow.com/q/171003/23118) and Apple is doing its best to [eliminate everything that is not officially blessed](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2092367?start=0&tstart=0).